# How to make a VBA word code run faster?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found this code online to search and highlight multiple words. It takes roughly about 10 min to run it on a 15 page document. I was wondering if it could be made to run any faster.

```
Sub HighlightMultipleWords()
Dim Word As Range
Dim WordCollection(2) As String
Dim Words As Variant
'Define list.
'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
WordCollection(0) = "word1"
WordCollection(1) = "word2"
WordCollection(2) = "word3"
'Set highlight color.
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
'Set highlight to replace setting.
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
'Highlight words when found.
For Each Word In ActiveDocument.Words
For Each Words In WordCollection
With Selection.Find
.Text = Words
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the nested loop?  It looks like that for every single word in the document you want to loop for each word in your collection (3 of them), executing a `ReplaceAll`?  You're examining every word and running these three replaces against them.  Lose the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: You might want to post this over at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Apart from removing the outer loop I would suggest renaming your variables `Word` and `Words` to avoid confusing them with... `Word` and `.Words`

Comment: @arcadeprecinct The code must be written or maintained by the author for the question to be on-topic for Code Review. Code that you found online is not eligible.

Comment: @200_success Oh of course, somehow I missed that this wasn't OP's code (although it should be hard to miss...), sorry!

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Indeed, the poster should have cited the source of the code. Posting code without attribution is not cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are all correct here, you only need to run the find and replace once per item in your list, you are running it multiple times by the amount of words in the document.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightMultipleWords()
Dim AryWords(2) As String
Dim VntStore    As Variant

'Define list.
'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
AryWords(0) = "word1"
AryWords(1) = "word2"
AryWords(2) = "word3"

'Set highlight color.
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
With Selection.Find
    'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting

    'Set highlight to replace setting.
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True

    'Process the array
    For Each VntStore In AryWords
        .Execute FindText:=VntStore, _
                 MatchCase:=False, _
                 MatchWholeWord:=False, _
                 MatchWildcards:=False, _
                 MatchSoundsLike:=False, _
                 MatchAllWordForms:=False, _
                 Forward:=True, _
                 Wrap:=wdFindContinue, _
                 Format:=True, _
                 Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
End With

End Sub
```